# SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4 , adding service

Tags: angular

I keep receiving  the error

> Error: Unexpected value 'SignupService' declared by the module 'SignupModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

though I already inject all the dependency on the SignupModule
here's my code

```
//SignupModule 
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SignupRoutingModule } from './signup-routing.module';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup.component';

import {SignupService} from './signup.component.service';


@NgModule({
 imports: [
   CommonModule,
   FormsModule,
   SignupRoutingModule
],
declarations: [
  SignupComponent,
   SignupService]
})
export class SignupModule { }
```

> here is the signup.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { routerTransition } from '../router.animations';

import { SignupService } from './signup.component.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss'],
  animations: [routerTransition()],
  providers:[ SignupService]
})

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
 user:user;

  constructor(signupService:SignupService) {
    console.log(signupService.register());
    this.user={
        firstName:'',
        middleName:'',
        lastName:'',
        gender:'',
        email:'',
        password:'',
        repeatPassword:''
    }
 }

ngOnInit() { }

signup(){
    console.log(this.user);
 }
}


interface user{
  firstName:string,
  middleName:string,
  lastName:string,
  gender:string,
  email:string,
  password:string,
  repeatPassword:string
}
```

> here is the signup.component.service

```
export class SignupService{
register(){
    console.log('service');
    return 'test';
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove SignupService from the declaration section of the app.module.ts and try..

Comment: yeah you're right i already solved it earlier :) thanks by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services has to be provided not declared.Remove **SignupService** from the declaration section of the app.module.ts .It should do the trick.

Comment: glad to help :)